# Setting template or drawing layout to print map ol5

Tags: openlayers

I have created a portal which export map and then print. I just wanted to add template or draw layout in canvas for that pdf as shown in the picture below.

Here is my code:

```js
//print map
var dims = {
  a0: [1189, 841],
  a1: [841, 594],
  a2: [594, 420],
  a3: [420, 297],
  a4: [297, 210],
  a5: [210, 148]
};

var exportElement = document.getElementById("export-pdf");
exportElement.addEventListener(
  "click",
  function(e) {
    exportElement.disabled = true;
    document.body.style.cursor = "progress";

    var format = document.getElementById("format").value;
    var resolution = document.getElementById("resolution").value;
    var buttonLabelElement = document.getElementById("button-label");
    var label = buttonLabelElement.innerText;
    var scale = 4000;

    var mapView = map.getView();
    var mapProjection = mapView.getProjection();
    var mapResolutionAtEquator = mapView.getResolution();
    var viewCenter = mapView.getCenter();
    var mapPointResolution = ol.proj.getPointResolution(
      mapProjection,
      mapResolutionAtEquator,
      viewCenter
    );

    var dim = dims[format];
    var width = Math.round((dim[0] * resolution) / 25.4);
    var height = Math.round((dim[1] * resolution) / 25.4);
    var size = map.getSize();
    var extent = map.getView().calculateExtent(size);

    var mapView = map.getView();
    var currZoom = mapView.getZoom();
    var mapProjection = mapView.getProjection();
    var mapResolutionAtEquator = mapView.getResolution();
    var viewCenter = mapView.getCenter();
    var mapResolutionAtEquator = mapView.getResolution();
    var mapPointResolution = ol.proj.getPointResolution(
      mapProjection,
      mapResolutionAtEquator,
      viewCenter
    );
    var mapResolutionFactor = mapResolutionAtEquator / mapPointResolution;
    var pdf_name = dist + "_" + tahsil + "_" + village + ".pdf";

    map.once("rendercomplete", function(event) {
      var canvas = event.context.canvas;
      showText(event.context, "left-top", dist, tahsil, village);
      drawLegend(event.context, "right-bottom");
      drawNorthArrow(event.context, "right-top");

      WriteScaletoCanvas(event);
      var data = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
      var pdf = new jsPDF("landscape", undefined, format);
      pdf.addImage(data, "JPEG", 0, 0, dim[0], dim[1]);
      pdf.save(pdf_name);
      map.setSize(size);
      // map.getView().fit(extent, size);
      mapView.setZoom(currZoom);
      exportElement.disabled = false;
      document.body.style.cursor = "auto";
    });

    var printPointResolution = (scale * 25.4) / (resolution * 1000); // edit1: corrected
    var printResolutionAtEquator = mapResolutionFactor * printPointResolution;
    var printZoom = mapView.getZoomForResolution(printResolutionAtEquator);

    map.setSize([width, height]);
    // mapView.fit(extent, (map.getSize()));
    mapView.setZoom(printZoom);
  },
  false
);
```

For example:

[image]

How to create this layout pdf?

Comment: Take a look at the ol-ext source code http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/ There are controls for title, scale lines, attributions, graticule borders, compass, etc. on the canvas.  Obviously not exactly what you want but you could use the same technique to produce your own.

Comment: thanks Mike but i did not see scaling option like 1:4000 and so on for printing map.

Comment: I don't think there is any other way than creating svg template and than drawing it to canvas before export to pdf, the same way you are now drawing legend, title, scale and compass.

Comment: is it possible to set everything in template according to scale and then give print-preview option then print map in desired paper size as A0

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use [mapfish](http://mapfish.github.io/mapfish-print-doc/#/overview). It comes in a shapre of .war application that can sit nicely on tomcat (or other) next to geoserver. Geoserver has also got a [buil-in version of mapfish](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/printing/index.html) that can be added as an extension but the versions there is outdated.

[Link to gif showing it in action.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wmSlLB4zOnx0fo53ol0ay2HaXbkfQRoo/view?usp=sharing)

I use it for the exact same purpose and it works great. 
Have a look at their documentation and if this is the way you want to go let me know and I can give some more details on how to set it up.

Comment: i think in mapfish a0 and a1 size printing not present.

Comment: You can set whaever size you want. Malfish uses jasper report's templates. Super customizable.